# Improving A Proof that the Product Orientation can orient $M \times N$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

Show that if $M$ and
$N$ are oriented corresponding to
forms $\omega \in \Omega^m(M)$
and $\eta \in \Omega^n(N)$
then $M \times N$ has an orientation
corresponding to the
form $\pi_M^*\omega \wedge \pi_N^*\eta$,
where $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$ denote
projection onto $M$ and $N$, respectively.
This is called the product orientation.

So far I have a, what I think is basic, start at a proof.

To show $M \times N$ has an orientation corresponding to the form $\pi_{M}^{*} \omega \wedge \pi_{N}^{*} \eta$, we need to show that it is non-vanishing. We already know that $\omega$ and $\eta$ are non-vanishing forms if they are restricted to $M$ and $N$ respectivley. Thus, if we pull back along the projections $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$ the form $\pi_{M}^{*} \omega \wedge \pi_{N}^{*} \eta$ will be non-vanishing since if have coordinates for $M$ and $N$ they will remain independent in $M \times N$ from the definition of $\times$.

I'm not sure how to prove that the basis for $\pi_M^* \omega$ and $\pi_N^* \eta$ will be independent. I've heard words like transverse thrown around occasionally which I think is related. Would that help here?

Comment: Have you tried e-mailing Dylan yet? We're also confused...